# JDBC create a boolean column in postgreslq

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc

I hava a spring boot application which defines some entity classes. As database I use postgresql (JDBC: 42.2.1).

I want to have a boolean column in the database but when declaring a variable boolean in the enity java class, this variable is translated to BIT in the column type.

How can I achive this, to have a boolean column in Postgresql.

Comment: did you tried `Boolean` instead of `boolean`?

Comment: yes, is the same. Aparently is due to the JDBC connection, in which a boolean is translated to bit. But I want to overwrite this.

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using? Which dialect did you configure. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you are using JDBC, why tag it as JPA? If using JPA then why tag as JDBC?

Comment: I don't use a dialect. It is all preconfigured from spring boot. It is a way to achive this if I declare a dialect?

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect. I added this in application properties but nothing changes.

Comment: It's not going to fix your problem, but `PostgreSQLDialect` is deprecated (it is technically the dialect for PostgreSQL 8.2), use one more appropriate for your version, eg `PostgreSQL95Dialect` (latest available in Hibernate 5.2.x).